# Use Custom Post Archive Page for a specific Custom Post

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, custom-post-type

I'm stuck on this issue with my Wordpress setup.  My current setup is as follows: I have a custom post type "degrees" that are categorized by undergraduate, graduate, online, and abroad.  The initial page is a specific taxonomy template I have set up for the user to specify which degrees to look through.  Once a category is selected, the user will come to a landing page with all graduate programs, etc.  This page is handled in the backend as a archive-degrees.php.  Then, upon selecting a program, the template used is single-degrees.php.  My problem is that I have one program (currently using the single-degress.php) that I would like to use the archive page as it needs to list out sub-programs.  I hope that makes sense.  Basically, I need this one specific Custom Post to use the archive page and then the single page for its sub-children.  I am not sure if there is a way to do this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to [specialized page templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Specialized_Page_Template). Your best bet is to create a new template for this page specifically.

From the Codex:

> **Create a template for one Page:** For more extensive changes, intended for just one specific Page, you can create a specialized template file, named with that Page's slug or ID:
>
> 1. page-{slug}.php
> 2. page-{ID}.php
>
> For example: Your About page has a slug of 'about' and an ID of 6. If your active Theme's folder has a file named page-about.php or page-6.php, then WordPress will automatically find and use that file to render the About page

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I understand this concept, I was just wondering if there was a better way to do this.  Also, if I go this route what is the best way to make sure the sub-posts use the single-degrees template?

Comment: This won't affect the sub-posts at all. If they're actually pages, they'll automatically inherit the correct template.

Comment: mevius, one question.  When I attempt this, my single-degrees template is overriding the specific page template.  Is there something I need to do to allow the page template to override the single page?

Comment: It's possible the template hasn't been named properly...what's the name of your specific page template?